# Missing a terraform's private virtual network in Azure resource

Tags: azure, terraform

I am looking for advice. I am working in Azure, attempting to set up a private virtual network between my Azure Function and its storage. Going through the Web UI, I can create the needed Private Endpoints, connect them to the same subnet, have a private DNS server with proper FQDNs, and have it working.

I need to reproduce this setup in terriform. I can create a private DNS, a subnet on the VNET, the storage, and the function. What I cannot do is get the function to talk to the storage.

Below are two screenshots, one created through the UI and the other through my terraform script. I am missing part of the Custom DNS record. The section tying the private link to the IP. I would like to know if I am missing an Azure terraform resource. After the screenshot, I have included the relevant terraform code.

[image: Web UI Version]
[image: Terraformed Version]

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "private_dns_zone" {
  name                = "sample1114.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" {
  name                  = "sample1114-vnet-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  registration_enabled  = false
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "storage_endpoint_table" {
  name                = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnetstorage.id
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.name
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.id
    subresource_names              = ["table"]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "storage_endpoint_table" {
  name                = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.name
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.storage_endpoint_table.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}
```

Comment: I may have the answer, adding an "azurerm_private_dns_virtual_network_link" seems to add the missing section to the private link's DNS entry, but I have not tested it all together in my code.

Thanks to https://jeffreyjblanchard.medium.com/azure-private-endpoints-and-terraform-85450fe9861c for the article.

Answer (score 1):

Reading over the blog [azure-private-endpoints-and-terraform](https://jeffreyjblanchard.medium.com/azure-private-endpoints-and-terraform-85450fe9861c), found the answer.  I needed to add an `azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link` resource to by terraform file.

The final block of logic I came up with is

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "private_dns_zone" {
    name                = "privatelink.table.core.windows.net"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" {
    name                  = "private-vnet-link"
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.name
    virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "storage_endpoint_table" {
    name                = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.name
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnetstorage.id 
    private_dns_zone_group {
        name = "default"
        private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.id]
    }
    private_service_connection {
        name                           = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.name
        is_manual_connection           = false
        private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.tablestorageaccount.id
        subresource_names              = ["table"]
    }
}
```